# Pipe the content of the current buffer into an external command and then read the output into a new empty buffer?

Tags: buffers, external-command, ex-mode

I've established that it's possible to take the contents of a buffer (even one that isn't saved anywhere) and [pipe it to a command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867410/18149).

like so: `:w ! petit --wordcount`

But! Is it possible to take the output of said command and pipe it back out to a new empty buffer in vim, without writing the output to a file...just writing back into a new buffer...using ex?

Comment: I think I found a way to do that here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output

Comment: Related: [Creating and destroying temporary files by vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22683/creating-and-destroying-temporary-files-by-vim).

Answer (score 2):

From the gist "[Redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)" by romainl:

```
function! Redir(cmd)
    for win in range(1, winnr('$'))
        if getwinvar(win, 'scratch')
            execute win . 'windo close'
        endif
    endfor
    if a:cmd =~ '^!'
        execute "let output = system('" . substitute(a:cmd, '^!', '', '') . "')"
    else
        redir => output
        execute a:cmd
        redir END
    endif
    vnew
    let w:scratch = 1
    setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
    call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Redir silent call Redir(<f-args>)

" Usage:
"   :Redir hi ............. show the full output of command ':hi' in a scratch window
"   :Redir !ls -al ........ show the full output of command ':!ls -al' in a scratch window
```

It captures the result with `execute "let output = system()"` and writes it to a new split. Untested:

```
:Redir !petit --wordcount %
```

`%` is replaced with the current file name, see `:help c_%`.