# Creating and destroying temporary files by vim

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

I integrated `luacheck` in `vim` with the following simple function:

```
function! LuaCheck()
  let errors=system("luacheck " . expand("%"))
  cexpr errors
  cwindow 5
endfunction
autocmd FileType lua nnoremap <buffer> <c-f> :call LuaCheck()<cr>
autocmd FileType lua set efm=%f:%l:%c:\ %m
```

It is working, but here is a problem: `luacheck` doesn't have interactive mode, it works only with files. So I have to use `expand("%")` instead of `getline(1, "$")`. When I changed something in buffer I need to save it before checking - it is bad practice. I want to create a temporary file, save content of buffer to it, check temporary file and remove it. But I don't know how to create the temporary file in `vimscript`. Is this possible? Or I need use external tools for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create temporary file name with `:h tempname()`:

```
let tempname = tempname()
call writefile([ "hello world" ], tempname)
" do something with tempname file
" ...
call delete(tempname)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to this problem. Assuming your Vim `has('job')` you can do:

```
let temp = bufadd('noname')
call setbufvar(temp, '&buftype', 'nofile')
call bufload(temp)
let job = job_start('luacheck', #{in_io: 'buffer', in_buf: bufnr(),
    \ out_io: 'buffer', out_buf: temp,
    \ exit_cb: {id, status -> execute(printf('cb %d | bw %d | cw 5', temp, temp))}
    \ })
```

Comment: Consider adding `err_io: "buffer", err_buf: l:buffer` to the job options and simplifying the callback to `execute("sb" . temp)`.